# Proving of an inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation

I'm trying to go about proving that
$$x > \sqrt{x} - 1\quad\mbox{for all $x >2$}$$
My first inclination was to try and prove the relationship by some form of induction. However it appears as tho the question is not leading me this way, could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Would it be easier to show $(x+1)^2>x$ then take square root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that
$$x-\sqrt{x}+1=\left(\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}\geq \frac{3}{4}>0.$$
So the inequality holds for all $x\geq 0$.

Comment: unfortunatly I'm still slightly lost
Will that not give me 

(sqrt(x) -1/2) > sqrt (-3/4)

Comment: The key word is "complete the square". See my edited answer.

Comment: ahhhh ok I see, so we've then gone on to say that because it will always be greater that 3/4 for all x > 0 then the original inequality must hold true

Comment: Yes, we proved a stronger inequality.

Answer (score 1):

$(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1 >x$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$. So
$$x+1 > \sqrt x$$
which gives the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is correct for all $\mathbb{R} \ni x \ge 0$. To show this you can begin by $(\sqrt{x}-1)^2  \ge 0$,  so $x \ge 2\sqrt{x}-1$ and notice that for $x \ge 0$ you can write $2\sqrt{x}-1 \ge \sqrt{x} -1 $. Therefore you get
$$ x \ge 2\sqrt{x} -1 \ge \sqrt{x} -1 , \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^{\ge 0}.$$